# error integrating PHP into HTML

Tags: php, html, vs-web-site-project

I got a forum in PHP and I got a website in HTML

I need to utilize the website template "to unify the appearance" to output the forum contents 
 I got stuck when I wanted to include the PHP code into the html file

I used the

```
<?php echo "here goes my PHP code" ?>
```

but it does nothing to me :(

so can I get some help to move forward in my development

I have tried and get tired of Posting the code piece here so I decided to post the question and try to figure out the code posting later if needed

thanks anyway

Comment: Could you post the exact code you are using to try and put your 'PHP code into the HTML file'?

Comment: what you want echo html tag on php...

Comment: have you renamed the `.html` file to `.php`?

Comment: are you using `php` code in `.html` file?

Comment: Define `it does nothing` a bit more specific.

Comment: what your html code dear.i want to try

Comment: Can u post your code here..?

Comment: it work fine.i use many times.

Comment: but here comment field doesn't accept the code is tooo long "I guess" is there another way to do it

Comment: Just edit your question!

Comment: that one doesn't help as well buddy......It's unbelievable that I can't get out of this issue that is just simply can't post the code because of formatting it

Comment: have you tried opening it in browser? Copy that file in your htdocs folder. Let us say name of file is test.php Open browser and type url as http://localhost/test.php . I guess you are directly giving path

Answer (score 1):

If it "does nothing" then the web server (if there is one) is probably passing the file "as-is" to the browser, and the browser is interpreting it as an unknown tag.

You must:

- Access the page through a web server
- Be using a web server that supports PHP
- Have the web server configured to treat that file as PHP (by default, on most systems, this is done by giving the file a .php file extension)

Comment: well I'm editing the file in dreamweaver and run it from there using the "Live" function button......will it help running it form my server I'm using Xammp ??   thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

> wanted to include the PHP code into the html

HTML is usually not processed by PHP. Only files (in default configuration) that end with *.php are passed thru PHP interpreter. If these HTML files you are willing to alter are standalone files (and you access them directly like `http://domain/file.html`), then you can try to enforce PHP there. If your server is Apache and you can tune its settings with `.htaccess` file (or if you can alter main Apache's configuration) then you can try adding this to your `.htaccess`

```
<Files "*.html">
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

If you are aiming at HTML templates then basically you are out of luck as these files are not going thru webserver but are read by i.e. your forum and usually **processed** (not executed etc) inside the code. Slight chances are that forum uses i.e. Smarty templating engine and you can tweak the forum code to enable PHP in Smarty templates.

**EDIT**

For PhpBB `.htaccess` won't do the trick, as these HTML files are plain templates. However you can enable PHP in templates in Security Settings. Just set "yes" to "enable PHP in templates". Once you do that you can use PHP code, but while PHP code itself is the same, PHP blocks are marked differently than usual `<?php` and `?>`. Instead of

```
<?php echo "Test"; ?>
```

you need to wrtite

```
<!-- PHP --> echo "test"; <!-- ENDPHP -->
```

Comment: well my forum is from PHPBB. and I tried to edit the .htaccess file in my websote folder unfortunatelly IT DOES NOT HAVE IT.....I have no clue WHY is that?......

Comment: if it does not have it then you can create it yourself. It's just plain text file named `.htaccess`. Anyway, it will not work anyway. See edited answer

Comment: guys I can't post my code I've been trying for hours I'm going crazy......any way how to show my code.....Please help